# Jupyter Notebook Preview on Github: Numbered List are Messed Up

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I uploaded a Jupyter notebook I've been working to Github for others to use. I used markdown cells to number steps within a set of procedures (e.g., 1, 2, 3, ...); however, when I preview the file in Github, it replaces the step numbers (1, 2, 3, ...) with 1, 1, 1, ... --only 1's!

Does anyone know why this happens and if there are any fixes to this? I didn't type all 1's in my .ipynb file.

What it looks like in the Jupyter notebook editor:

[image]

What it looks like in the Github preview:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Jupyter Notebooks just happen to be weird and there doesn't seem to be a good fix, I just changed my numbers 1., 2., 3., ... to 1), 2), 3), ....

While it removes the indentation, it still looks okay while actually preserving the numbered steps in my "how to" guide.